# When writing a Gradle plugin, is there a way to always run task during check phase?

Tags: java, gradle, gradle-plugin

I'm trying to write a gradle plugin, and have been more or less successful to this point. The task can be executed with 'gradle myTask' in any project it is applied to at this point.

However, I want the task to be executed during every build (to be exact during the 'check' phase). On the side of the project this is pretty easy by adding:

```
check {
    dependsOn myTask
}
```

pretty easily. What I would like to do is to apply the same behavior on the plugins side, so the task is always executed during the check phase, no matter which project the plugin is applied to.

I was thinking about code similiar to this:

```
TaskContainer tasks = project.getTasks();

MyTask myTask = tasks.create(TASK_NAME, MyTask.class);

Task checkTask = tasks.findByPath("check");

if(checkTask != null) {
    checkTask.dependsOn(myTask);
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. The check phase runs, without error, but myTask is never executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no phase called `check`, there is only a taks called `check` that is added to the project when you add it yourself or when you apply a plugin like for example `java` that adds this task.

I assume you apply your plugin before applying the plugin that adds the `check` task and thus your `null` check fails and no dependency is added.

You can either require that your plugin is applied after the plugin that adds the `check` task or you need to make your plugin more flexible e. g. by doing something like

```
if (checkTask != null) {
    checkTask.dependsOn(myTask);
} else {
    tasks.whenTaskAdded(task -> {
        if ("check".equals(task.getName())) {
            task.dependsOn(myTask);
         }
    });
}
```